# Android Understand Storage Paths

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage, android-memory, internal-storage

I want to save file on phone. **`new File(directory, myCustomFolder)`**.

- My files are large and MP3

1 - **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** is not always access to save file. On some phones that don't have sd card not available and return nothing. :(

2 - **getFilesDir()** after unistall my app my files remove. (Is not the right place to store files) :(

3 - **getCacheDir()** after unistall my app my files remove. (Is not the right place to store files) :(

4 - **getDataDirectory()** after unistall my app my files remove. (Is not the right place to store files) :(

- Now, How do I distinguish the right place and secure and always available to save my files?
- I need a SD card if there was not, I have my files stored on internal memory and the public(Public means no save to *data app folder*). ?!!
- Apps like WhatsApp and Telegram how to make folder into two external memory and internal memory?

*Please help me.Thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` GOOD WORKING.

solution is: android API 23+ need check dangerous permission:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a folder for your app in the Downloads folder. It will always be there. You can access it via `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DI‌​RECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`. And since you are saving files, it makes it even a more appropriate place to store it, don't you think so?

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DI‌​RECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` is always available and exists and writable and mkDires() is true?

Comment: Yes, it's always available. You can also use `mkdir()` to create folders in it (e.g. storage/emulated/0/Downloads/YourFolderHere)

Comment: some phones have two storage and two `DI‌​‌​RECTORY_DOWNLOADS`, so Which selected for save file? (example: storage/sdcard0/Downloads/YourFolderHere    -------    storage/sdcard1/Downloads/YourFolderHere)

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I meant is to store the files in the emulated storage, not the portable one (i.e. sd card, usb, etc). Take a look at the method again. It is `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, not `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. By using `mkdir()`, you can create folders in it, and it will stay there regardless or not your user keeps or uninstall your app, unless they manually delete the folder.

Comment: i test on samsung note5  `File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DI‌​‌​RECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "MyFolder").mkDires();` but not working and can not to create folder. and too `File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFolder").mkDires();` why? :(